# Change background Drawable for all views

Tags: java, android

I have a grid view which contains a lot of cells. Each cell contains a button.
According to some conditions I set a Drawable background to some buttons using this code:

```
calendarView.getChildAt(selected_range.get(i))
            .findViewById(R.id.calendar_day_gridcell)
            .setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.calendar_button_selected));
```

Later I want to find all buttons with background Drawable "calendar_button_selected" only. Which I set before and change all of them to another background Drawable.

I can loop through all views but I do not know how to get  the name of the used drawble. "calendar_button_selected" in my case.

How to achieve this task?

Comment: Instead of checking for the background drawable, you can check for the conditions which are used for setting the drawable for the gridView.

Comment: it is not easy in my case ... the best solution is to change all views which has specific background... i can loop through all views but i do not know how to check the view and get the drawzble name

Comment: I can loop through all views but i do not know how to get  the name of the used drawble ... "calendar_button_selected" in my case